# Can I create Where clause in Couchbase Lite swift on runtime from array of conditions?

Tags: swift, couchbase, couchbase-lite, sql++

I am using **Couchbase Lite 2.6,** 
I want to build my query on runtime, I am receiving a list of conditions(["Key":"value"]) via an API using which I need to filter my local database and display the values.

Is there any way I can do that using **QueryBuilder?**

I found a similar discussion on Couchbase forum but it's quite old so the solution is not valid anymore.

https://forums.couchbase.com/t/filter-on-array-filed-in-couchbase-and-couchbase-lite/3983/4

Comment: please mention the reason to downvote the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give you an example for android and you can extrapolate that to swift:

```
    String name = "foo";
    String surname = "bar";
    Expression ex = Expression.property("type").equalTo(Expression.string("user"));
    if(name != null) {
        ex.and(Expression.property("name").equalTo(Expression.string(name)));
    }

    if(surname != null) {
        ex.and(Expression.property("surname").equalTo(Expression.string(surname)));
    }

    Query query = QueryBuilder
            .select(SelectResult.all())
            .from(DataSource.database(DatabaseManager.getDatabase()))
            .where(ex)
            .limit(Expression.intValue(10));
```

Answer (score 2):

Since this question was for Swift, It would be nice to have the answer in swift:
It's the same code mentioned by @deniswsrosa but in siwft.

```
  let name = "foo";
    let surname = "bar";
    let ex = Expression.property("type").equalTo(Expression.string("user"));
    if(name != nil) {
        ex.and(Expression.property("name").equalTo(Expression.string(name)));
    }

    if(surname != nil) {
        ex.and(Expression.property("surname").equalTo(Expression.string(surname)));
    }

    let query = QueryBuilder
            .select(SelectResult.all())
            .from(DataSource.database(DatabaseManager.getDatabase()))
            .where(ex)
            .limit(Expression.int(10));
```